# Wordpress просит ftp доступ и не переходит по ссылкам (выдает 404)

Tags: linux, wordpress, ftp

Залил сайт с локалки на сервер vds, настраивал сам linux ubuntu v18.
Ну вот заработал сайт. загрузилась главная страница, кликнул на ссылку новости выдало ошибку 404. 
решил установить плагин. Wordpress начал запрашивать ftp доступ.

когда создаю страницу говорит ошибка публикации.

НО. Когда я меняю в настройках постоянные ссылки на простые, ссылки начинают работать и страницы создаются. Но плагины по прежнему не устанавливаются**

вот такие вот симптомы. Помогите вылечить сайт ) 
Может я сервак не верно настроил.

Кто встречал такую проблему помогите плз с:

Comment: Как переносисили, если не плагинами типа Duplicator - причина номер 1.

Comment: WP запрашивает доступ, когда права установлены неправильно. Должно быть 644 на файлы, 755 на папки. Владелец файлов - ТОТ, под которым выполняется php (или apache, что там у вас).

Comment: @KAGGDesign конкретные "циферки" в целом не важны - какие  по дефолту выданы те и правильные. Важен именно владелец.

Comment: @plaglamist, да, и сервак неправильно настроен и ВП неправильно перенесён.

Comment: @KAGGDesign 644 и 755 — это чтобы любой соседний пользователь на том же хостинге мог все файлы беспрепятственно прочитать?)

Comment: @andreymal vds в вопросе видно или не очень?

Comment: @KAGGDesign окей, 644 и 755 — это чтобы любой соседний пользователь на том же vds мог все файлы беспрепятственно прочитать?)

Comment: @andreymal какие еще соседние пользователи на своем сервере

Comment: @KAGGDesign те самые, которые админ своего сервера добровольно пустил на свой сервер. На моём личном vds я добровольно и безвозмездно хостю ещё троих знакомых пользователей с разными ботами, например

Comment: @andreymal это фантазии, не имеющие отношения к вопросу. В вопросе об этом ни слова.

Comment: @KAGGDesign лучше перебдеть, чем недобдеть, и не ставить чтение всем без крайней необходимости. А то такими рассуждениями можно дойти до чего-то вроде «Зачем хешировать пароли, взломы это фантазии, в вопросе об этом ни слова»

Comment: @KAGGDesign ,  Права поставил 777. Может из-за них ? А что означает - Владелец файлов - ТОТ, под которым выполняется php (или apache, что там у вас). ?? КАК узнать кто владелец и как им стать . ubuntu команду подскажите)

Comment: я захожу на сервак под root и с него делал все настройки

Comment: Но я создал еще одного пользователя. у которого есть доступ sudo

Comment: @plaglamist владельца надо смотреть командой `ls -l` или в Modnight Commander, или в WinSCP, FileZilla - все есть. Сменить владельца: `chown -R www-data:` Скорее всего, в ubuntu 18 пользователь `php - www-data:www-data`